# Passenger Apache for Rails not server public/ assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I am having a big problem with my rails app which I am trying to deploy on a VPS.
I have some files in the rails app public/ folder such as public/javascripts/home-menu.js and also I use Sprocket to precompiled into public/assets.

In my production.rb setting

```
config.serve_static_assets = false #i want to serve through Apache not rails
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

While the rails app is serving fine, all files on public/ directory cannot be served. The error is shown below.

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-fbbe68455909a54f6d39e01d3ab38d34.js"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I reckon that it is something wrong with Apache setting so I went in to check. Having CPanel, Apache setting is set automatically. I added the below to *"/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/gadgettr/mydomain.com/*.conf"*

```
  <Directory /home/gadgettr/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews

     #Options FollowSymLinks
     #AllowOverride None
     #Order allow,deny
     #Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

And in the http.conf

```
<VirtualHost 103.15.232.XXX:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/gadgettr/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
UseCanonicalName Off

## User gadgettr # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
UserDir enabled gadgettr
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup gadgettr gadgettr
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup gadgettr gadgettr
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid gadgettr gadgettr
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID gadgettr gadgettr
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/gadgettr/public_html/cgi-bin/

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/gadgettr/gadgettrader.sg/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

I cannot change the DocumentRoot /home/gadgettr/public_html so I create an alias
    ln -s /home/gadgettr/public /home/gadgettr/public_html

However I cannot solve my problem and still get the same routing error. Why is Apache not serving my static file?

Spent an entire day debugging this... Really need all the help I can have! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Why do you have a Javascript folder in your Public directory?  Why don't you use the javascript folder in the assets directory or the javascript folder in the Vendor directory?

Comment: Have you tried following this guide? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger

Comment: When i put the javascript in public/assets folder, i get a precompiled error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem! It is permission problem

The issue started because I use 'root' user to create /home/gadgettr. thus the owner is root not gadgettr. To solve this problem, use WHM delete the user and recreate a new one. then instead of using root to setup your rails app, use the user created.

This should solve everything :)

Comment: I learned this the hard way as well.  Installing as root will really mess up your system like nothing else.